# How to tell wsimport to use an httpproxy into generated classes

Tags: java, wsdl, wsimport, http-proxy

With **wsimport** command included in JDK6 it is possible to generate the Java classes needed to invoke a Web Service, starting from it's WSDL.

Once these classes are generated however, they may be used from within a network with an **Http-Proxy**.

The optimal solution for this should be to leverage the [`URL.openConnection(Proxy proxy)` API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html) instead of other system-wide (via system properties or with a ProxySelector) methods.

Is it possible to tell the wsimport command to use a given http-proxy into the generated code?

Please note that [among the wsimport option](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/wsimport.html) there is also `-httpproxy:<host>:<port>`, but this is used only for allowing the generation behind an Http Proxy and the option has no effect on generated code.
Further, looking at the generated classes there is not even an explicit call to URL.openConnection(), so apparently there is no way to override this behaviour.

Comment: I would also like to know the answer. Anyone please help

Answer (score 0):

I think that there is no way to actually generate stubs with the proxy they are going to be used with. In fact why they should be? Stubs are just stubs, a representation derived from wsdl. Why should they know about proxy? If the same application is moved to other system with different proxy, then code needs to be changed i.e stubs needs to be generated again with the knowledge of new proxy. This is clearly undesirable. So in my knowledge I don't think that's even a possibility.